# VUE.JS + Bootstrap - How to capitalize first letter in the same input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I would like get in input capitalize first letter when I'm starting write.

```js
<b-form-input v-model="formSurname" id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" maxlength="50" required> </b-form-input>
```

I have also filter for this. But `v-model="formSurname | capitalize"` doesn't work I tried `:value="formSurname | capitalize"` but it doesn't work too

```js
Vue.filter("capitalize", function (value) {
    if (!value) 
        return '';
    value = value.toString();
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
});
```

How to make an input to change my first letter in real time?

Comment: This is literally one of the examples they give in the vuejs Filters docs :) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: It does specify that to use it on v-bind, you need 2.1.0+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to **store** the value with the uppercase, use a computed property with set and get methods :

```
computed: {
 formSurnameCapital: {
    get: function () {
      return this.formSurname;
    },
    // setter
    set: function (newSurname) {
      if(newSurname.length < 1) {this.formSurname = ''; return}
      this.formSurname = newSurname.replace(/^./, newSurname[0].toUpperCase());
    }
  }
}
```

And in your template :

```
<b-form-input v-model="formSurnameCapital" id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" maxlength="50" required> </b-form-input>
```

Else, if is just about displaying it uppercase, you can simply use css :

```
.toCapitalFirst {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It works well `newSurname,length` there should be dot :)
It's helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, thats a typo. great. Glad I helped ;)

Comment: @Raffobaffo it has one weird issue if the value is already entered and you try to change the first letter i.e remove first letter it will make second letter capital and move the cursor at the end of the text seems like very hard to update the first letter of the text if its entered.

Answer (score -2):

You can update the your `formSurname` on a `keyup` event in your `methods`

```
<b-form-input v-model="formSurname" id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" maxlength="50" required @keyup="formatSurname"> </b-form-input>
```

And in methods:

```
formatSurname() {
  if (this.formSurname) {
    this.formSurname = this.formSurname.toString()
    this.formSurname = this.formSurname.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.formSurname.slice(1)
  }
}
```